# Regex does not match according to python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, byte

I am working on a program that needs to match some bytes to a regex.
Since I am working with bytes, my regex and data are both the python type `bytes`.
I'm not sure if the next part is relevant so you can propably skip to the last 3 lines and help me find out why the regex does not match the 16 bytes. Thank you!

My regex is:

```
regex = b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00.{16}\x17\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00WalkDown'
```

I know it could be shorter to achieve the same result but this regex is auto-generated by the program itself so I can't change it.

I am trying to match this regex with this data:

```
data = b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`,z\x11#\x00\x00\x00k\x004\x00\r\x00\n\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00WalkDown'
```

This is the python code I am using to match them:

```
import re
print(re.match(regex, data))
```

This prints out `None` so I think the regex does not match with the data.

Since I am not testing for a string but for bytes, I can't use any online regex debuggers because they only support string regex.

I tried to replace the 16 unknown bytes with "1" in my data like this and it matches the regex:

```
data = b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x001111111111111111\x17\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00WalkDown'
```

I think this shows that the error is in the .{16} part. So I used python to check the length of the corresponding part:

```
len(b'`,z\x11#\x00\x00\x00k\x004\x00\r\x00\n\x00')
```

returns `16`. And it should be 16.

So why do these 16 bytes not match the regex `b'.{16}'`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the data that you're trying to match contain a newline character.

Try this: `re.match(regex, data, re.DOTALL)`. The `DOTALL` flag will make sure `.` matches *any* byte, including newline.